# How Would You Monitor Remaining Drive Space for VM Servers?

Tags: virtualization, monitoring, hard-drive

We've got most of our servers as Virtual Machines.  Every once in a while, they get low on disc space.  I'm not the guy who manages them, but obviously, I'm affected by this.  I want to somehow monitor the remaining disc space on the servers I'm concerned about.  What would you do?

Points to help your answer:

- I can have full admin rights to the
  server if needed.
- The servers are W2K3 using VMWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, build yourself a WMI script.

[MSDN - WMI Tasks: Disks and File Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Virtual Centre, then you can either configure alerts centrally.

If your not afraid of a bit of database digging, the drive size and freespace is stored in a database table, and it's not too difficult to punch this up onto a HTML page with a bit of scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is a good way to go.

Comment: Forgot to mention the platform.  I've now included that.